# Customising just a single property in a Resource

Tags: activeadmin

I have a simple Rails Model which has several columns in the database. I then have an ActiveAdmin Resource for this model and by default it renders me a nice `index`, `show` and `form` views with all of the columns and I'm able to do all the standard CRUD operations.

Is it possible to customise one of the columns without overwriting `index`, `show` and `form` functions and writing out all of the individual columns again?

For example if I want to change how a single column is rendered I know I can do this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
    permit_params :name, :description, :price, :weight

    index do
        selectable_column
        column :id
        column :name
        column :description
        column :price do |f|
            text_field "#{f.price} EUR"
        end
    end

    show do
        row :id
        row :name
        row :description
        row :price do |f|
            text_field "#{f.price} EUR"
        end
        row :weight
    end
end
```

But I would instead like to do something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
    permit_params :name, :description, :price, :weight

    # param_view is (to my knowlege) an imaginary method
    param_view :price do |p|
        text_field "#{f.price} EUR"
    end
end
```

Is this somehow possible? What about just hiding a single property?

Comment: There is no out of the box active admin way for this. I was researching and then saw you are working on it :-) https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/7087